# BC30002 Error Unable to reference .net standard 2.0 components from .net framework 4.8

Tags: .net-standard-2.0

I have a .net standard 2.0 C# project which simply has the following content in one of the C# files:

```
namespace person.contact
{
    public class contactDetail
    {
        public long contactNumber { get; set; }
        public decimal contactAmount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I also have a .net framework 4.8 project in VB.NET that now references this project using a project reference that points to the .CSPROJ location

Within the .net framework 4.8 project, one of my files calls up the above public class like so:

```
Dim clientContact As New person.contact.contactDetail
clientContact.ContactNumber = 12345
clientContact.contactAmouunt = 1.00
```

Now my VS 2019 can go to the definition when I F12 on contactDetail in the vb file and runs without a problem. When I do a clean build though I face the error:

```
error BC30002: Type 'person.contact.contactDetail' is not defined.
```

Both projects are also signed however I do know that as .net standard is higher there could be an issue with the DLL? I have however had this working before.

Answer (score 0):

May be, because of multiple reference of different version exist in you project. remove all references and add again the single reference.